# Extract Data from Sql and display to excel using vba

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am trying to join data from two sql tables. **Table1 should have columns FileID, AccName, number,ut _score,uw_score**

**Table 2** should have columns **FileID , label, data(contains y/N answers) and AdditionalComments.** There are list of questions displayed under column **Label**. I need to look into last three questions(under the column LABEL) and post the result only if the answers are **No**

Both these tables can be identified with the unique file id, that is associated with every accountname. So I need to join the table that has only the columns as mentioned above.

```
                   Option Explicit

        Sub GetDataFromADO()

       'Declare variables'
        Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command
        Dim objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim iCols As Integer
        Dim tbl As ListObject

        Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
        Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

        'Open Connection'
        objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source= .;Initial Catalog=.;Trusted_connection=Yes;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
        objMyConn.Open

        'Dim sSqL As String
        'Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
        'sSqL = "Select FileID, AccName, number,ut _score,uw_score from AUT.dbo.LIST"
        'objMyConn.Execute sSqL

        'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
        Dim u As String
        Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
        objMyCmd.CommandText = "select AccName, Underwriter, Auditor,UT_Score,Underwriter_Score from Actuarial.dbo.Audit_Checklist"
        objMyCmd.CommandText = "Select Label, Data, AdditinalComments from Actuarial.dbo.List_data"
        objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        objMyCmd.Execute


        'Open Recordset'
        Set objMyRecordset.Source = objMyCmd
        objMyRecordset.Open
        For iCols = 0 To objMyRecordset.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = objMyRecordset.Fields(iCols).name
        Next

        'Copy Data to Excel'
        Worksheets("Data").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objMyRecordset

        End Sub
```

Here is the sql query, that I need to include conditions to select last 6 values from the **Label** column of table 2. Kindly apologize for the naive where clause that i used. Appreciate any help on this !

```
   SELECT Reports.dbo.tbl1.AccName,Reports.dbo.tbl1.Underwriter,
   Reports.dbo.tbl1.Auditor, Reports.dbo.tbl1.UT_Score, 
   Reports.dbo.tbl1.Underwriter_Score,       Reports.dbo.tbl2.Label,Reports.dbo.tbl2.Data, Reports.dbo.tbl2.AdditinalComments
  FROM Reports.dbo.tbl1
  INNER JOIN Reports.dbo.tbl2
  ON Reports.dbo.tbl1.FileID=Reports.dbo.tbl2.FileID;

  Where Reports.dbo.tbl2.Label='Is it profitable?'  OR  'When is effective date expiring ? ' OR 'Did the community accept?';
```

**Output that I get now **

[image: Output that I get now]

**Expected Result**[image: Expected]

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with VBA, Excel, or ADODB. This is truly just a SQL question. You are going to need to use a single statement with a 'JOIN` to bring the two tables together. To get a good answer here, please share some sample data from the two tables and your desired results. Then you can use the SQL statement for your `.commandText`.

Comment: JNevill I included the sql query script above

Comment: Can you post sample data and an example of what you are expecting the output to look like?

Comment: I posted the data above. the second picture is what i am expecting the result looks like